# Is there an Immediately Invoked Anonymous Function for Java?

Tags: java, lambda

For example, I might want to do an assignment like this (in JavaScript):

```
var x = (function () {
    // do some searching/calculating
    return 12345;
})();
```

And in Java, how can I do something similar with Lambdas? The compiler does not
like something like this:

```
Item similarItem = () -> {
    for (Item i : POSSIBLE_ITEMS) {
        if (i.name.equals(this.name)) return i;
    }
    return null;
}();
```

Comment: Why would you want this? What does your javascript code do differently because it's in an IIFE?

Comment: I don't think it is possible because the compiler needs to know which functional interface is the lambda exactly implementing.

Comment: If you want code which runs immediately, write code without the lambda.

Comment: I also don't get the point of declaring a function with no name to run it in place., Maybe you gain something from that in Javascript, but not in Java.

Comment: The point of an IIFE in JavaScript is mostly scope containment; Java's scoping rules are different (and consistent!), and the idiom does not apply.

Comment: @chrylis Good point. I was trying to use it to break the method up into even littler functions, so the scope part is even more irrelevant. I guess in JavaScript you would use nested functions rather than IIFE, which would be even more annoying to do in Java if you used nested classes

Comment: @PeterLawrey Consider `class A { int a; void setA(int a) { this.a = a; } }`. To make an initialized instance, you do `A a1 = new A(); a1.setA(1);`. To make a `Stream` of 10 `A`s, you'd have to declare 10 dummy variables and then do `Stream.of(a1, ..., a10);` or create kludgy helper methods (in cases where there are a lot of setters). With immediately-invoked anonymous lambdas, you could do away with that or similar "workarounds" that also keep the initialization code in the same place. I find it very useful in some instances, e.g. unit tests.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No because lambdas need a target type. The best you can do is cast the expression:

```
Item similarItem = ((Supplier<Item>) (() -> {
    for (Item i : POSSIBLE_ITEMS) {
        if (i.name.equals(this.name)) return i;
    }
    return null;
})).get();
```

You must use the correct Functional Interface for your particular lambda. As you can see, it is very clunky and not useful.

---

**UPDATE**

The above code is a direct translation of the JavaScript code. However, converting code directly will not always give the best result.

In Java you'd actually use [**streams**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description) to do what that code is doing:

```
Item similarItem = POSSIBLE_ITEMS.stream()
                                 .filter(i -> i.name.equals(this.name))
                                 .findFirst()
                                 .orElse(null);
```

The above code assumes that `POSSIBLE_ITEMS` is a `Collection`, likely a `List`. If it is an array, use this instead:

```
Item similarItem = Arrays.stream(POSSIBLE_ITEMS)
                         .filter(i -> i.name.equals(this.name))
                         .findFirst()
                         .orElse(null);
```

Comment: I liked you answer, but found it incomplete, so I expanded on it rather than create a new answer. Hope that's ok.

Comment: I love the stream idea! Reminds me of Gulp! Are the streams any less efficient speed or memory-wise than the collection Iterator?

Comment: They're slower and less efficient. https://blog.takipi.com/benchmark-how-java-8-lambdas-and-streams-can-make-your-code-5-times-slower/ Usually, at least. The question then becomes: Does it matter? It almost always does not.